# Rails 6: uninitialized constant ActionText::Engine::ApplicationController (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

```
Puma caught this error: uninitialized constant ActionText::Engine::ApplicationController (NameError)
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actiontext-6.0.1/lib/action_text/engine.rb:43:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `instance_exec'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:429:in `block in make_lambda'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in halting'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:607:in `block (2 levels) in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `catch'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:606:in `block in default_terminator'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:202:in `block in halting'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `block in invoke_before'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `each'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:514:in `invoke_before'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:134:in `run_callbacks'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:119:in `complete!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `ensure in block in run!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:76:in `block in run!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `tap'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-6.0.1/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:70:in `run!'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-2.0.7/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-6.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:83:in `call'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/webpacker-4.2.0/lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/rack-proxy-0.6.5/lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/railties-6.0.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:526:in `call'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:228:in `call'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/server.rb:667:in `handle_request'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/server.rb:470:in `process_client'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/server.rb:328:in `block in run'
C:/Ruby26-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/puma-4.3.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:134:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please note that this post does not constitute an appropriate question for this site. You should take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then come back here and update your post based on _all_ the guidelines there. Specifically, you need to include an actual question in your post, the steps you've taken to resolve the issue, an explanation of how you got there, and preferably a [mre].

Comment: Can you reproduce this on a *new* Rails project?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely your app is missing `ApplicationController` class. can you double-check the case please if it's present under `app/controllers/application_controller.rb`

If you don't find the file straightaway, don't be worried! It may be likely that your app is structured in such a way that does not depend on defining `ApplicationController`. ActionText has a long-standing issue, due to which you may have difficulty in using it.

You can keep track of this open issue that discusses about using `ActionText` in projects which do **NOT** depend on default `ApplicationController` class: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37183

If this is not your case, then you can simply overcome the issue by creating the class in the above mentioned directory.

Enjoy!

Comment: I've run into this issue and still had the application_controller present in the right place.

Comment: @courtsimas would you take the chance to create a new post with the backtrace along with the app controller and config/application.rb files. you may share the post link here if you like me to take a look :)

Comment: If you have ApplicationController, check for syntax errors there